# How to bypass cloudflare authentication using postman?

Tags: postman, cloudflare

I'm testing an App and I need to hit the API directly for some modifications on the API side. The problem is that I'm getting blocked by cloudflare. When I make an API call I always get the response to login to cloudflare.

Does anyone know how can I bypass this cloudflare validation?

BTW, I don't mean to work around it or anything, I have the credentials, I just don't know where to use them on postman.

Comment: Hey! It seems that no one could helped you because the famous answer "it depends" may arise. In my case, we have cookies that needed to be set in each request, and if they were missing on a request, Cloudflare shows up again. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue. The recommendation from the postman team was the following:

- Have the company VPN IP whitelisted in CF. This will bypass CF interference in manual and runner requests.
- For Monitors, which run from a third-party server, Edit the monitor to use one of the two static IPs listed under "Manually select Region". Your CloudFlare admin must whitelist the IP.

  - NOTE: Your team may be unwilling to whitelist this IP.
  - A header-based bypass did not work for us.
- Determine which calls trigger the rule, and why, so that you can avoid triggering alarms. Work around the problem, basically.